# Why I have to use python-dotenv in order to load env variables to Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

I am trying to read in a python script some variables that I have in an environment file `myfile.env`:

```
LOCALHOST='1'
```

If in my python script I just run:

```
import os
print(os.environ)
```

It prints:

```
environ({'PATH': '....', 'HOSTNAME': '...', 'PYCHARM_HOSTED': '1', 'PYTHONUNBUFFERED': '1'})
```

But in these array I don't have the `LOCALHOST` variable. I found that I can use `python-dotenv` and now I see it and working, but I don't get why I have to use it, and it's not feasible to load them only using `os` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a .env file is not the environment.

`os.environ` gets data from the environment which, somewhat oversimplified, is a string-to-string (name-to-value) mapping maintained by the operating system for each process, and inherited by child processes. Things are typically put there using `export` statements in a shell – they will then be inherited by all processes started from that shell — but there are other ways.

`.env` files are an application-level thing; the operating system does *not* know about them and they are *not* automatically loaded into the environment (and hence *not* picked up by `os.environ`). That is what python-dotenv takes care of for you.

Comment: Great thanks, and using docker, and setting env_file parameter doesnt load that file to the `os.environment`?